# Cannot access my PostgreSQL on Windows, Although I have postgreSQL and pgAdmin installed on system

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I have installed PostgreSQL-15.3 and pgAdmin 4 on my system, and set up everything requires, but I am facing this error.

This is the error I am facing

[image]

I have data showing on pgAdmin

[image]

Comment: Please dont post images.  Do you have the PW setup/added to the DB that may not be in your code?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I followed a video step by step, and my system is showing this error. do I need to install any dependencies?

Comment: psql is not in your PATH.  As I recall, on Windows you need to configure PATH yourself, the installed doesn't do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

The error you get when you type the command `psql -U postgres postgres` occurs because you do not have *psql* added to your PATH environment variable.

To fix it, click **Windows** > search for **Edit the System Environment Variables**, and open it. The System Properties window should appear. Click on **Environment Variables** at the bottom right > Select **PATH** and click on **Edit**. Now, click on **New** and add the path to the bin folder of your PostgreSQL installation (it may be similar to C:\ProgramFiles\PostgreSQL\15\bin).

Finally, close all command prompts or terminals and reopen them to effect the changes.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add psql to the path environment variable as the configuration needs to be done manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is error is of environmental variables. To solve this, go to the *psql* executable in the Postgresql *bin* directory and add that directory path to the environmental variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you have psql added to your environment path. You can add that manually and try the command again.